# Bootstrap issue. Why my right panel doesn't fill the whole space

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have developed a small UI using Bootstrap CSS. I'm far to be an expert. Unfortunately I have a issue with my right panel.

I have pushed my code on Jsfiddle here -> https://jsfiddle.net/camsellem/e4dddfw3/

```
    <div class="col-xs-3 col-lg-3">
        <div class="panel panel-info" style="position:fixed;">
            <div class="panel-heading">Suggested products</div>
            <div class="panel-body">
                <div id="products-suggest" class="list-group"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

It's not obvious because we can't open it in full screen but actually the right panel named "Suggested products" never fill the whole space. There is always a blank gap between the end of the panel and end the end of the container. I tried different layouts but no success. it's more obvious on this screenshot.

[image]

Any help appreciated.

Cheers

Comment: how many columns do the other panels in the row fill?

Comment: it's because `.container` width limitations. Try to use `.col-xs-12` instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add this css in this class

```
.panel.panel-info {
    width: 23%;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/e4dddfw3/3/

Answer (score 1):

[Working fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/e4dddfw3/6/)

Add a class `fixed` to this `<div class="col-xs-3 col-lg-3 fixed">` and add the following css

```
.col-xs-3.col-lg-3.fixed{ 
   position: fixed;
   right: 0;
   width: 25%;
}
```

remove `position:fixed` from `<div class="panel panel-info" style="position:fixed;">`

Answer (score 0):

Position fixed given to `panel-info` class, is causing that problem:

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6">
      <img src="img/talend-logo.png">
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6 text-right">
      <!-- <img src="img/cloudera-logo.png"> -->
      <img src="img/hortonworks-logo.png">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="row" style="padding-top:50px;">
      <div class="col-xs-9 col-lg-9">
        <div class="alert alert-info" style="padding:15px">
          For data-driven businesses it’s no longer enough just to have the right information, they need the right information, right now.
          <br \>
          <br \> Take Amazon for example, they found that delaying their data by just one second could end up costing them $1.6 billion in sales. Why? Today’s customers are accustomed to incredibly fast-paced standards when it comes to online services. Businesses
          that can’t serve up pricing and product recommendations in real-time fall behind.
          <br \> The business benefits of transforming into a data-driven organization are unprecedented. So how should you go about putting your big data to work? Talend 6, the first integration platform on Spark, is a good start.
          <br \>
          <br \> Talend 6 on Spark allows you to take full advantage of real-time analytics, and employ features such as predictive recommendations, dynamic pricing and more.
        </div>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-xs-6 col-lg-4">
            <div class="thumbnail">
              <img class="group list-group-image" src="img/online-offer.png" alt="" />
              <div class="caption">
                <h4 class="group" style="color:#00A3AD">Basics Bundle</h4>
                <p class="group">
                  200GB Data + unlimited standard local and national calls + Fetch TV + 3 months of Stan bonus
                </p>
                <div class="row">
                  <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6">
                    <p class="lead" style="color:#00A3AD">From $70</p>
                  </div>
                  <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6">
                    <input type="hidden" class="product-id" value="1">
                    <input type='submit' name=".$post->ID." value="Submit" class="btn btn-success product-click">
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="col-xs-6 col-lg-4">
            <div class="thumbnail">
              <img class="group list-group-image" src="img/online-offer.png" alt="" />
              <div class="caption">
                <h4 class="group" style="color:#00A3AD">Big Bundle</h4>
                <p class="group">
                  Unlimited data + unlimited talk to selected countries + Fetch TV + 3 months of Stan bonus
                </p>
                <div class="row">
                  <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6">
                    <p class="lead" style="color:#00A3AD">From $95</p>
                  </div>
                  <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6">
                    <input type="hidden" class="product-id" value="2">
                    <input type='submit' name=".$post->ID." value="Submit" class="btn btn-success product-click">
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="col-xs-6 col-lg-4">
            <div class="thumbnail">
              <img class="group list-group-image" src="img/online-offer.png" alt="" />
              <div class="caption">
                <h4 class="group" style="color:#00A3AD">Entertainement Starter</h4>
                <p class="group">
                  Unlimited Data + Unlimited std calls and national calls + Fetch TV + 3 months of Stan bonus
                </p>
                <div class="row">
                  <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6">
                    <p class="lead" style="color:#00A3AD">From $90</p>
                  </div>
                  <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6">
                    <input type="hidden" class="product-id" value="3">
                    <input type='submit' name=".$post->ID." value="Submit" class="btn btn-success product-click">
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="col-xs-6 col-lg-4">
            <div class="thumbnail">
              <img class="group list-group-image" src="img/online-offer.png" alt="" />
              <div class="caption">
                <h4 class="group" style="color:#00A3AD">Entertainement Bundle</h4>
                <p class="group">
                  Unlimited Data + Unlimited standard calls and national calls + Fetch TV + 3 months of Stan bonus
                </p>
                <div class="row">
                  <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6">
                    <p class="lead" style="color:#00A3AD">From $95</p>
                  </div>
                  <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6">
                    <input type="hidden" class="product-id" value="4">
                    <input type='submit' name=".$post->ID." value="Submit" class="btn btn-success product-click">
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="col-xs-6 col-lg-4">
            <div class="thumbnail">
              <img class="group list-group-image" src="img/online-offer.png" alt="" />
              <div class="caption">
                <h4 class="group" style="color:#00A3AD">Ultimate Bundle</h4>
                <p class="group">
                  Unlimited Data + Unlimited standard local and national calls + Unlimited standard national calls to mobiles + Unlimited standard international calls to selected countries + Fetch TV + 3 months of Stan bonus
                </p>
                <div class="row">
                  <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6">
                    <p class="lead" style="color:#00A3AD">From $115</p>
                  </div>
                  <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6">
                    <input type="hidden" class="product-id" value="5">
                    <input type='submit' name=".$post->ID." value="Submit" class="btn btn-success product-click">
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>



        </div>
        <!--/row-->
      </div>
      <!--/.col-xs-12.col-sm-9-->
      <div class="col-xs-3 col-lg-3">
        <div class="panel panel-info" style="width:100%">
          <div class="panel-heading">Suggested products</div>
          <div class="panel-body">
            <div id="products-suggest" class="list-group"></div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!--/row-->
    <hr>
  </div>
  <!--/.container-->
</div>
```

Comment: Actually I want the panel to scroll when I scroll down :)

Comment: But, why did you put inside a bootstrap column, cus anyway it will expand that parent width?

Comment: So, if you want that, give a percent width to this class, and you will achieve that! :)

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to modify the line
`<div class="col-xs-3 col-lg-3">` to `<div class="col-xs-3 col-lg-3 pull-right">`